# Re-writing a view that uses condition join [OR]

Tags: performance, t-sql, join, view

I have this view that is performing really bad, and the problem is its build on joins that use or conditions

I have tried re-writing this for the past 2 days, using CTE and UNION but the result is incorrect

Maybe you guys can help, just few ideas how to do it, because I am completely lost.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Amazon_Listings]
AS

SELECT
DISTINCT
    ISNULL(a.MerchantId, b.MerchantId) AS MerchantId
    , ISNULL(a.SKU, b.[seller-sku]) AS SKU
    , ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0) AS NONFBAQTY
    , ISNULL(b.[Quantity Available], 0) AS FBAQTY
    , ISNULL(a.[ASIN], b.[ASIN]) AS [ASIN]

    , CASE
        WHEN salePrices.SKU IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (salePrices.SalePrice * vamm.USDConversionRate)), 9999)
        ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (a.Price * vamm.USDConversionRate)), 9999)
        END AS Price
    , CASE ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0)
        WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(b.[Quantity Available], 0)
        ELSE ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0)
        END AS Quantity
    --a.ReportRequestId,
    , CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(b.[Quantity Available], 0) > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS IsFBAed
    , CASE WHEN c.[seller-sku] IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS IsRestricted--,
--a.ReportRequestId RegReportRequestID, b.ReportRequestId FBAReportRequestID, c.ReportRequestID CancReportRequestID
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , MerchantId
            , SKU
            , [ASIN]
            , Price
            , CASE Quantity
                WHEN '' THEN 0
                ELSE Quantity
                END AS Quantity
            , ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.Amazon_Listings_Raw WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE RIGHT(SKU,4) <> '__ON'  
            AND ReportRequestId IN 
            (
                SELECT 
                MAX(ReportRequestId)
                FROM v_Amazon_Listings_Raw WITH (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY MerchantId
            )
    ) AS a
FULL JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            b.ID
            , b.MerchantId
            , b.[seller-sku]
            , b.[fulfillment-channel-sku]
            , b.[ASIN]
            , b.[condition-type]
            , b.[Warehouse-Condition-code]
            , b.[Quantity Available]
            , b.ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.[Amazon_FBA_Listings_Raw] AS b WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE 
            ReportRequestId IN 
                (
                    SELECT
                    MAX(ReportRequestId)
                    FROM [v_Amazon_FBA_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    GROUP BY MerchantId
                )
            AND [Warehouse-Condition-code] = 'Sellable'
    ) AS b
    ON a.MerchantId = b.MerchantId
    AND a.SKU = b.[seller-sku]
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , MerchantId
            , [item-name]
            , [item-description]
            , [seller-sku]
            , Price
            , Quantity
            , [image-url]
            , [item-is-marketplace]
            , [product-id-type]
            , [zshop-shipping-fee]
            , [item-note]
            , [item-condition]
            , [zshop-category1]
            , [zshop-browse-path]
            , [zshop-storefront-feature]
            , asin1
            , asin2
            , asin3
            , [will-ship-internationally]
            , [expedited-shipping]
            , [zshop-boldface]
            , [product-id]
            , ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.[Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE RIGHT([seller-sku],4) <> '__ON'
            AND ReportRequestId IN 
            (
                SELECT MAX(ReportRequestId)
                FROM [v_Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY MerchantId
            )
    ) AS c
    ON (a.MerchantId = c.MerchantId OR b.MerchantId = c.MerchantId)
    AND (b.[seller-sku] = c.[seller-sku] OR a.SKU = c.[seller-sku])

INNER JOIN V_Amazon_Marketplace_Merchants vamm
    ON (a.MerchantId = vamm.MerchantID OR b.MerchantId = vamm.MerchantId)
LEFT JOIN AmazonOurPrices salePrices WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON vamm.MerchantId = salePrices.MerchantId
    AND a.SKU = salePrices.SKU
    AND salePrices.SalePrice <> salePrices.RegularPrice
```

This is what I have come up with, its runs really fast 20 seconds,
but the data is off, not sure what I am missing or doing wrong.
any help would be glady appreciated

```
CREATE VIEW AMZ_NOTUSED_12_22_2017
as

WITH A ( MerchantID,Sku,Asin,Price,Quantity, [Seller-Sku],SalePrice,USDConversionRate,salePricesSKU,[Quantity Available])
AS
(

SELECT  a.MerchantId,a.SKU,a.ASIN,a.Price,a.Quantity, c.[seller-sku],salePrices.SalePrice,vamm.USDConversionRate,salePrices.SKU AS salePricesSKU,'' [Quantity Available]

FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , MerchantId
            , SKU
            , [ASIN]
            , Price
            , CASE Quantity
                WHEN '' THEN 0
                ELSE Quantity
                END AS Quantity
            , ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.Amazon_Listings_Raw WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE RIGHT(SKU,4) <> '__ON' 
            AND ReportRequestId IN 
            (
                SELECT 
                MAX(ReportRequestId)
                FROM v_Amazon_Listings_Raw WITH (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY MerchantId
            )
    ) AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , MerchantId
            , [item-name]
            , [item-description]
            , [seller-sku]
            , Price
            , Quantity
            , [image-url]
            , [item-is-marketplace]
            , [product-id-type]
            , [zshop-shipping-fee]
            , [item-note]
            , [item-condition]
            , [zshop-category1]
            , [zshop-browse-path]
            , [zshop-storefront-feature]
            , asin1
            , asin2
            , asin3
            , [will-ship-internationally]
            , [expedited-shipping]
            , [zshop-boldface]
            , [product-id]
            , ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.[Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE RIGHT([seller-sku],4) <> '__ON'
            AND ReportRequestId IN 
            (
                SELECT MAX(ReportRequestId)
                FROM [v_Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY MerchantId
            )
    ) AS c
    ON a.MerchantId = c.MerchantId and a.SKU = c.[seller-sku] 
INNER JOIN V_Amazon_Marketplace_Merchants vamm
    ON a.MerchantId = vamm.MerchantID 
LEFT JOIN AmazonOurPrices salePrices WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON vamm.MerchantId = salePrices.MerchantId
    AND a.SKU = salePrices.SKU
    AND salePrices.SalePrice <> salePrices.RegularPrice

    )

    ,


    B AS 
    (

SELECT b.MerchantId,
b.[Seller-SKU] AS Sku,
b.ASIN, 
c.Price, 
c.quantity , 
c.[seller-sku], 
salePrices.SalePrice,
vamm.USDConversionRate,
salePrices.SKU AS salePricesSKU,
b.[Quantity Available]

FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            b.ID
            , b.MerchantId
            , b.[seller-sku]
            , b.[fulfillment-channel-sku]
            , b.[ASIN]
            , b.[condition-type]
            , b.[Warehouse-Condition-code]
            , b.[Quantity Available]
            , b.ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.[Amazon_FBA_Listings_Raw] AS b WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE 
            ReportRequestId IN 
                (
                    SELECT
                    MAX(ReportRequestId)
                    FROM [v_Amazon_FBA_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    GROUP BY MerchantId
                )
            AND [Warehouse-Condition-code] = 'Sellable'
    ) AS b
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , MerchantId
            , [item-name]
            , [item-description]
            , [seller-sku]
            , Price
            , Quantity
            , [image-url]
            , [item-is-marketplace]
            , [product-id-type]
            , [zshop-shipping-fee]
            , [item-note]
            , [item-condition]
            , [zshop-category1]
            , [zshop-browse-path]
            , [zshop-storefront-feature]
            , asin1
            , asin2
            , asin3
            , [will-ship-internationally]
            , [expedited-shipping]
            , [zshop-boldface]
            , [product-id]
            , ReportRequestId
        FROM dbo.[Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE RIGHT([seller-sku],4) <> '__ON'
            AND ReportRequestId IN 
            (
                SELECT MAX(ReportRequestId)
                FROM [v_Amazon_Cancelled_Listings_Raw] WITH (NOLOCK)
                GROUP BY MerchantId
            )
    ) AS c
    ON 
    b.[seller-sku] = c.[seller-sku] and b.MerchantId = c.MerchantId


INNER JOIN V_Amazon_Marketplace_Merchants vamm
    ON b.MerchantId = vamm.MerchantId
LEFT JOIN AmazonOurPrices salePrices WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON vamm.MerchantId = salePrices.MerchantId
    AND b.[Seller-SKU] = salePrices.SKU
    AND salePrices.SalePrice <> salePrices.RegularPrice 
    )
SELECT
DISTINCT
    a.MerchantId AS MerchantId
    , a.SKU
    , a.Quantity AS NONFBAQTY
    , ISNULL(a.[Quantity Available],0) AS FBAQTY
    , a.[ASIN] AS [ASIN]

    , CASE
        WHEN salePricesSKU IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (SalePrice * USDConversionRate)), 9999)
        ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (a.Price * USDConversionRate)), 9999)
        END AS Price
    , CASE ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0)
        WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(a.[Quantity Available], 0)
        ELSE ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0)
        END AS Quantity
    , CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.Quantity, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(a.[Quantity Available], 0) > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS IsFBAed
    , CASE WHEN a.[seller-sku] IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS IsRestricted
FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM a 
UNION 
SELECT * FRom B
) a
```

Comment: Hi Mark, this is not code review or code complete service. You should to write question that can helps other users, not just to you. Learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: to help us better understand, you should add script that create your tables and add some significative data. So we could run your query, see results and try to help you rewrite it for better performance. Without this it's very hard for us try to help you....

Comment: Are you sure that the condition in the original query is correct? Instead of `ON (a.MerchantId = c.MerchantId OR b.MerchantId = c.MerchantId) AND (b.[seller-sku] = c.[seller-sku] OR a.SKU = c.[seller-sku])` it seems more logical to have `ON a.MerchantId = c.MerchantId AND a.SKU = c.[seller-sku] OR b.MerchantId = c.MerchantId AND b.[seller-sku] = c.[seller-sku]`